# Creating entry in DB makes duplicates of passed variables instead of FKs

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

So, I've tried to create a new row in my Database (using EF4.0 Code-First)

```
courseRep.Create(new Course {
    Date = DateTime.Parse(date),
    Tutor = tutorRep.GetById(tutorId), // I get the correct Tutor
    Subject = subjectRep.GetById(subjectId) // and the correct Subject
});
```

But whats happening is that there will also for every execution a new Subject and new Teacher with the same Name created.

[image: Bert is now duplicated]

Also, Subject-Tutor is n:n, but there won't be an entry in the  associative Table SubjectTutors created.

Any hints?

**edit:** The beginning of my `RepositoryBase` looks like this:

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
{

    public void Create(TEntity o)
    {
        using (TContext db = new TContext())
        {
            db.Set<TEntity>().Add(o);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: what does the `Create` method do?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Is there any base class or interface `TEntity` ?

Comment: I added the first few lines of my base class. Now it should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to attach the reference first. The entity that is returned from `tutorRep` and `subjectRep` is not a proxy anymore, it's a disconnected object. EF doesn't know that it is an existing entity and EF will just mark all objects in the graph as added.

You need a way to attach the reference first.

```
db.Entry(o.Tutor).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
db.Entry(o.Subject).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Probably refactoring the create method, you can do reflection it you have a base class.

```
public class TEntity : BaseEntity
{
}

var references = o.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity))
    .Select(p => p.GetValue(o))
    .Where(t => t != null)
    .ToArray();
foreach (var reference in references)
{
    db.Entry(reference).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
db.Set<TEntity>().Add(o);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or if you have the FK id, `TutorId` and `SubjectId` on `Course`, you can just assign it.

```
courseRep.Create(new Course {
    Date = DateTime.Parse(date),
    TutorId = tutorId,
    SubjectId = subjectId
});
```

Comment: Where do I "attach the reference" exactly?

Comment: Changing the state to unchanged is the same as attach, in attach you can do like `db.Set<T>().Attach(x);`, but T will refers to `Course` when creating a new `Course` where you want to attach `Tutor` to `db.Set<Tutor>()` and `Subject` to `db.Set<Subject>()`

Comment: But I used the exact same class for more projects and it worked fine. The problem must be somewhere else. Probably the Entities or the code at the very top.

Comment: probably in _more projects_, the reference is retrieved from the same `DbContext`, where it's tracked by EF (it's a proxy), you can check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx) if you are not sure, ... _not only is the state of the root entity marked “Added,” but everything in the graph that the context_ **was not previously aware of** _is marked Added as well_

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions may be right, but I found a very simple one, which worked for me in my case fine:

```
courseRep.Create(new Course {
    Date = DateTime.Parse(date),
    TutorId = tutorId, // instead of Tutor = ...
    SubjectId = subjectId // instead of Subject = ...
});
```

Instead of passing the reference of the Tutor and Subject, I pass the Id's and that did the Trick.

Comment: Did you see that it's part on my answer?